# 500 Internal Server Error With PDF Merger PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers, pdf-generation, fpdf

Recently, I upgraded my Google Chrome to the latest version and now because of this I can't generate PDFs anymore on my "live" site, however, the strange part is I still can on my "test" site.

Both my sites are on the same server, using the same code; so I don't know why PDF merger works on one site and not the other.

Has anyone had this same issue?

This is an issue now with all web browsers and not just Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure the references to FPDF and the like are correct on your live site? It's not uncommon for a path to change between test and live.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your browser choice affects incidents of 500 error. What does your server log say in relation to these errors?